# UNNESTして取得したJSONをgroup byしたい。

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

BigQueryでJSONでキー指定されて保存されたカラムをUNNESTして、["11","24"]の状態で取得できたのですが、
これを更にUNNESTしてc(11や24など)でgroup by したいのですが、下記SQLだとエラーになってしまいます。
どのように記載すれば、下記のような表になるでしょうか？
test|11
test|24

```
WITH
data AS (
SELECT 
"test" as a,
["11","24"] c
)
SELECT c,count(*) cnt from data
,UNNEST(c)
group by c
```

Answer (score 0):

このスクリプトを試してください:

```
WITH
  data AS (
    SELECT "test" AS a, ["11", "24"] AS c
  ),
  unnested AS (
    SELECT a, c_value
    FROM data, UNNEST(c) AS c_value
  )
SELECT a, c_value, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM unnested
GROUP BY a, c_value
```

これにより、次の出力が得られます。

```
a    | c_value | cnt
-----|---------|-----
test | 11      | 1
test | 24      | 1
```

これは問題の解決に役立ちますか?